# Get country and city with HTTPS

Tags: php, ssl, https, ip, ssl-certificate

I am currently using the code below but I want an equivalent that uses HTTPS so that the browser does say that my page contains unsecured information.

```
<?php
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
if(isset($geo)) {
    $city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
    $region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];
    $country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];   
    }
elseif(!isset($geo)){
    $city = "NaN";
    $region = "NaN";
    $country = "NaN";   
    }
?>
```

Ideas?

Comment: You mean 'doesn't'? Have you actually tried it? This should work if your PHP page is served over https and you have installed a valid certificate. Note that it is PHP, your server, retrieving the geo information, not the browser of the client.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Geoplugin.net requires a valid API key to access their API via HTTPS (therefore possibly only allowing premium users to access data via HTTPS). 
The best choice for you will be contacting them about your enquiry.